# Javascript syntax for jQuery .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax, load

I've just attempted to make a simple script to use ajax to load a new part of a page.  The class remove/add to change the relevant text colour works fine.  However, the new html does not seem to appear.  I have a feeling this is to do with my general js syntax but I can't work it out.

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#page_menu a").click(function() {
            $("#page_menu p").removeClass("current");
            $(this).children().addClass("current");

            var project = $(this).attr("name");
            var loadUrl = project + ".html";

            $("#project_image").load(loadUrl);

            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

An example of an anchor tag in the html would be:

```
<a name=example href="#">Example</a>
```

The html file I'm looking to load would be called "example.html" and the code in it:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

I'm sure it's pretty straight-forward but I'm just not seeing it!

Cheers,

Rich

Comment: Basic debugging first. Does the request get fired? Is the html file name really valid? Does `#project_image` exist, and only once?

Comment: To clarify Pekka's comment: you should use the Firebug extension in Firefox, or the Developer Tools built-in to Chrome/Safari to look at the javascript console, etc. and see if there are any errors and if the AJAX request is being sent at all.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? There is a Bug with the $.load Method in 1.5. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8125 Next week jQ will serve an update which solves this problem.

Comment: the file name is definitely valid, #project image exists only once - and the request seems to be getting fired as I can place the add/remove class after the request and it still runs.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 - I've never used any debugging tool really.  Guess i better start looking at those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `href` of the anchor directly:

```
<a href="example.html">Example</a>
<div id="project_image"></div>
```

And then AJAXify it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#page_menu a').click(function() {
        $('#page_menu p').removeClass('current');
        $(this).children().addClass('current');
        $('#project_image').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I can get that to work if I set the href to the page I'm on (so I get a "window in a window" effect) but for some reason it will not do it for any other file.  Do I have to lay my external files out in more detail than just <p>Hello</p>?

Answer (score 1):

Anchor's most certainly do have a `name` attribute, so that part would be okay.. but to make things cleaner, change your anchor to:

```
<a href="example.html">Example</a>
```

For length sake you can use shorthand syntax for $(document).ready, and also do the class changes in one chain. Then just load the page specified in the href and to see if the request actually worked, add a callback, like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("#page_menu a").click(function(e) {
        $("#page_menu p").removeClass("current").filter(this).addClass("current");

        $("#project_image").load(this.href, function(res) {
            // This will allow you to see the response from the server without having to dig through requests
            // If you don't have a console for some reason, just change this to alert()
            console.log(res);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```